# How can I get the spring error count in a JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to do something conditionally in my JSP depending on if there are errors or not in my JSP, something like

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${errors.errorCount > 0}">
       <!-- do something -->
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

However, it always evaluates as false, even when there are errors.

What is the correct way to evaluate this?

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259194/cant-get-any-output-from-the-springhasbinderrors-taglib/5259325#5259325

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this in a `spring:bind` tag with the correct `name` attribute for it to populate `${errors}`:

```
<spring:bind name="yourstuff">
...
</spring:bind>
```